# How to calculate minimum number of operations to make a number divisible by another

Tags: c

I have a coding prompt I am trying to solve:

> You are given two positive integers `a` and `b`. In one move you can increase `a` by 1 (replace `a` with `a+1`). Your task is to find the minimum number of moves you need to do in order to make `a` divisible by `b`. It is possible that you have to make 0 moves, as `a` is already divisible by `b`. You have to answer `t` independent test cases.

> Input:
> The first line of the input contains `t(1<t<10000)` - the number of test cases then `t` test case follows
> the only line of the test case contains two integers `a,b(1<=a,b<=10^9)`

> Output:
> For each test case print the answer the minimum number of moves you need to do in order to `a` divisible by `b`

Here is my code:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  long long int t, a, b;
  int value, count = 0, i, j;
  scanf("%lld", &t);
  if (t >= 1 && t <= pow(10, 4))
  {
    for (j = 1; j <= t; j++)
    {
      scanf("%lld %lld", &a, &b);
      if ((a >= 1 && a <= pow(10, 9)) && (b >= 1 && b <= pow(10, 9)))
      {
        value = a;
        for (i = 1; a % b != 0; i++)
        {
          count++;
          a = (value + i);
        }

        printf("%d\n", count);
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        count = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and format the code. The indention is all over the place.

Comment: You have coded the instructions in the question verbatim, which obviously is not the most efficient thing to do. The question in online judges tend to be designed to make you run into TLEs, so that you have to think of a better algorithm. For example, if b is a large prime and a is a small number, you will end up checking a lot of numbers.

Comment: So-called "competition" or "online judge" sites are *not* a good way to learn programming or specific languages. Don't use them as such (unless you want to learn bad habits and sometimes even invalid code). If you really want to learn programming, invest in books and take computer-science classes. Once you know a few languages and have a couple of years of college-level CS studies behind you, use such sites as simple brain-teasers or puzzle sites, without any other use.

Comment: (Also, there's no need to include `<math.h>` so that you can write `10000` as `pow(10, 4)`. You don't have to check these numbers; tho judge guarantees that they are in the given range.)

Comment: Output the input values and `a % b` (in case of hidden test cases just invent a few). What does that value tell you about the number of move you will need?

Comment: I think this challenge is explicitly designed to make you understand TLE.

Comment: That is the real problem for you to solve. You start with a brute force solution to get a feel for the problem (and so you can make your own test cases), and develop a more efficient solution from there. Good luck and happy solving!

Comment: What's your question? Looks like you have a solution. Does it work? Do you get an error? See [mcve] for more information (among other relevant Help Center articles).

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me i have already solve it.....................

Answer (score 0):

( With [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) in mind I turn my comment into the first step of an answer according to the compromise desribed there. )

Hint 1:
Output the input values and `a % b` (in case of hidden test cases just invent a few). What does that value tell you about the number of moves you will need?